# Parameter values for non-zero real limit to exist

Tags: limits

Find values of a parameter a, so that the limit is a non-zero real number

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow \ 0} \left(\frac{e^{x*ln(1-x)}-1+x^2+ax^3}{x^4}\right) $

L'Hopital's Rule looks like a valid first step. Should I consecutively apply it four times to get a real number in the denominator and then, figure out the parameter value in the numerator to get a non-zero limit? Or are there better ways to approach the problem?

Comment: I would first separate the functions, e.g. $\lim_{x\to0} \frac {e^x + x^2}{x^4} = \lim_{x\to0} \frac {e^x}{x^4} + \lim_{x\to0} \frac {x^2}{x^4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start by

$$x\ln(1-x)=$$
$$-x^2-\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{x^4}{3}+x^4\epsilon(x)$$

and
$$e^X=1+X+\frac{X^2}{2}+X^2\epsilon(X).$$

thus

$$e^{x\ln(1-x)}=1-x^2-\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{x^4}{2}+x^4\epsilon(x)$$

and the numerator becomes
$$(a-\frac 12)x^3+x^4(\frac 16+\epsilon(x))$$

the limit will exist if
$$a=\frac 12$$
and the limit is
$$\frac 16$$